# Header html errors

Tags: html, css

I have been creating the menu for the main page of my website. First I made it in a drawing I wanted to pass it to html with figma it did not go well.

Now I want to create it pure code. But it doesn't turn out the way I want either.
link:
https://codepen.io/R3DW0LF/pen/ExVqYbo?

```
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="page-content-wrap">
                <div class="page-header-content">
                    <div class="dyna_logo img kfuwufhd">
                        <span>Dynamo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search__box">
                        <div class="srch_inpt" style="display: block;">
                            <input class="search_input efh473e" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inpts-tpbar">
                        <div class="tpbar login-top jfhejdyd" style="display: inline-flex;">
                            <div class="control-input login">
                                <a href="/signin">Hello</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-input register">
                                <a href="/singup">Hello 2</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>`
```

I want something like this:
[Design of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsK7q.png)

Comment: No, only i want help. I dont understand so much css.

Comment: What do you want help with? Where are you stuck in your code specifically?

Comment: the space below is larger than the one above. When I put another div and components it doesn't follow the rules.

For example: if I put float: right; it stays right there. And it is not at the same margin as the other divs. it is a little lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #edeef0;
    font-family: system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Open Sans, Helvetica Neue, "Noto Sans Armenian", "Noto Sans Bengali", "Noto Sans Cherokee", "Noto Sans Devanagari", "Noto Sans Ethiopic", "Noto Sans Georgian", "Noto Sans Hebrew", "Noto Sans Kannada", "Noto Sans Khmer", "Noto Sans Lao", "Noto Sans Osmanya", "Noto Sans Tamil", "Noto Sans Telugu", "Noto Sans Thai", sans-serif;
}

.page-header {
    position: absolute;
    height: 54px;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-header-content {
    background: #4A76A8;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

.page-header-content .dyna_logo {
    /* position: absolute; */
    margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top:5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
    /* identical to box height */
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.search__box {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.search__box .search_input {
    border: 0;
    width: 275px;
    line-height: 16px;
    transition: background-color 0.05s, color 0.05s;
    background: #224B7A url('/images/head_loupe.svg') no-repeat;
    background-position-x: left;
    background-position-y: 8px;
    background-position: left 8px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border-radius: 14px;
}

.search__box .efh473e {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 19px;
    height: 28px;
    border: none;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.search__box .efh473e:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.tpbar .control-input {
    padding:5px;
}

.login-top .control-input > a {
  color:black;
  align-self: center !important; 
  text-decoration:none;
}


.linkButton{
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-left:15px;
  border-color:#f0f0f0;
  border-style:solid;
  height:16px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  align-self: center;
}

/* Responsive style */

@media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    .inpts-tpbar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="app">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="page-content-wrap">
      <div class="page-header-content">
        <div class="dyna_logo img kfuwufhd">
          <span>Dynamo</span>
        </div>
        <div class="search__box">
          <div class="srch_inpt" style="display: block;">
            <input class="search_input efh473e" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inpts-tpbar">
          <div class="tpbar login-top jfhejdyd" style="display: inline-flex;">
            <div class="control-input linkButton">
              <a href="/signin">Sign in</a>
            </div>
            <div class="control-input linkButton">
              <a href="/singup">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: or just visit this link https://codepen.io/parth-mehta-the-vuer/pen/bGVXbQE

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to separate your page-content, you can try with `justify-content`:

```
.separate{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```